# cpp array difference between initial data

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, initialization

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int solution(int m, int n, vector<vector<int>> puddles) {
    const int MAXIMUM = 100;
    int paddlePosition = -1;

    int pos[MAXIMUM][MAXIMUM] {0};  //type 1
    //int pos[MAXIMUM][MAXIMUM];    //type 2
    for(auto puddle = puddles.begin(); puddle != puddles.end(); puddle++)
        pos[(*puddle)[1] - 1][(*puddle)[0] - 1] = paddlePosition;
    
    pos[0][0] = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < m; i++)
        if(pos[0][i] != paddlePosition)
            pos[0][i] = pos[0][i - 1];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if(pos[i][0] != paddlePosition)
            pos[i][0] = pos[i - 1][0];
    
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < m; j++)
        {
            if(pos[i][j] == paddlePosition);
            else if(pos[i - 1][j] == paddlePosition && pos[i][j - 1] == paddlePosition)
                pos[i][j] = paddlePosition;
            else if(pos[i - 1][j] == paddlePosition)
                pos[i][j] = pos[i][j - 1];
            else if(pos[i][j - 1] == paddlePosition)
                pos[i][j] = pos[i - 1][j];
            else
                pos[i][j] = (pos[i - 1][j] + pos[i][j - 1]) % 1000000007;
        }
    }
    
    int answer = pos[n - 1][m - 1];
    if(answer == paddlePosition)
        answer = 0;
    return answer;
}
```

this code has only one difference. pos array have initialization or not.

when i give parameter m = 100, n = 100, puddles = [[1, 1]] and access to pos[99][99], the value doesn't fixed without initialization.

i thought that double for phrase access data continously and boundary of array was initialized already so data will doesn't mattered without initialization(working like lazy initialization). but it was wrong.

why result is difference?

Comment: We have no idea, when, where, or how you're calling this function, no idea what `MAXIMUM` is, what `puddles` consists of, etc. -- *why result is difference?* -- Run your code in a debugger and inspect the `pos` array on each step.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh..the code was run on web coding test site, and i try to run this code on other web compiler after your comment read, it works right. i ask this question because thought it will occured by logical error but now i think it's web site error. sorry and thanks.

Comment: That does not mean your code is correct.  When you have an uninitialized variable, it can contain *any* value, including `0`.  So there is nothing wrong with the other website -- the issue is with your program.  You see that it works correctly if you initialize the values in the array -- why would the website all of a sudden start to work because you initialized the array?  Does that make sense to you?  I bet if we had a full program, and passed the parameters you specified, we would show you why it doesn't work, but you failed to post a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Now i found it. you're right. Uninitialization with random value. I know it before but I ignored because i will access continously so it doesn't matter to my code. I concerned about array range problem becuase non fixed value will be occured by memory error like segment fault with array. but random value which is sometimes with paddlePosition value makes an exception. I was fool... thanks for your help!